# Method to track lost packets source in FreeBSD

Tags: tcp, freebsd

I have FreeBSD host (some sort of HTTP Proxy) with spikes of retransmitted packets number. Is there any way to track were host loosing them (per incoming connection).

Answer (score 1):

I usually capture a bunch of them with tcpdump or similar; and then post process them elsewhere. In your case that should not be hard - as you just need the header.

Something like tcpdump (without; or a < 200 byte -s fly) would do on the target machine.

Compress/move this file then off to a desktop machine to work on it. I'd start with something like wireshark (simply use the filters).

Beyond that - simple grep-ing/wc-counting or a small perl script may be called for. To save you re-inventing histograms; consider http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/62-How-to-generate-a-histogram-with-Perl or do a quick google.